# If node is for small Web Applications not Enterprise why Linkedin shifted their mobile back end to node js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, knockout.js, node-modules

We use node js programming for fast and scalable product. But I have heard many opinions for node not being for Enterprise Applications. LinkedIn shifted their back end to node for mobile. Is there any big industry using node as their primary technology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well node.js is [highly used in big companies](https://www.tothenew.com/blog/how-are-10-global-companies-using-node-js-in-production/) nowadays. Each backend technology has its upsides for development and also its limitations. Facebook for example uses assembly in some parts of their big data processing to get the most out of every bit. If you are not relying in processing a thon of data, like Artificial Intelligence apps or any exponential use of data you are good with nodejs. As you can see in the article companies with hundreds of millions of users like Netflix uses nodejs to develop their web app... Now their software to process the data from its users it is definetly not using nodejs.